# Zener diode equation proof (chacteristic curve)

Tags: diodes, zener, graph, equation

I'm trying to prove this equation(at least I think that's the correct one):

[image]

which produces this graph:

[image]

I can prove the one that describes the PN diode but I am not sure what I should do differenly here. Any help would be appreciated!

**Note:** If anyone can point me somewhere I can find this proof I would be grateful as well.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist That's not what I'm looking for. The equation that I provide may not be the correct one but I would like the proof for the equation that produces the graph I provide.

Comment: This link has all the references you need

Comment: What do you mean by "prove", exactly? This is not an equation of some mathematical theory. It is derived from the physical model used to describe the workings of a PN diode and it has been verified experimentally (up to a point-it doesn't describe the breakdown region).

Comment: BTW, as @TonyEErocketscientist already told you, that Wikipedia article already explains how it is derived. If you really need the exact, step by step, derivation procedure you must be quite knowledgeable on quantum and solid-state physics. That's hard stuff to digest. Why do you need that? If you add some more detail on the problem you are trying to solve, we could be able to help you better.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati For example, to prove the equation for the PN diode I used the densities of the electrons and holes to find the currents on the opposite sides respectively and then find the total current of the diode. I'm looking for something similar to this.

Comment: Are you aware that the equation you posted (Shockley's equation) *is* the equation that (almost) corresponds to the graph you posted? And that is the equation you should have derived as the "PN junction equation". The difference lies in the fact that that equation, as I already said, doesn't explain the brakdown region (i.e. the region for V<Vz, where the reverse current increases dramatically).

Comment: @LorenzoDonati So you are the saying that the equation is the same for the two? Because the equation I have been given for the PN diode is slightly different. Mine doesn't have the η for example.

Comment: The book defines this in the 1st ref of my link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bell_System_Technical_Journal

Comment: Please, do read that article of Wikipedia. It explains the &eta; factor (ideality factor) presence. Your derivation neglects other effects that empirically led to "correct" the equation with the ideality factor. A Zener diode is basically a PN junction PN diode optimized to work in the breakdown region. This latter cannot be described by your model, since, in reality, is due to two different effects (Zener effect, a sort of quantum tunnelling effect, and avalanche breakdown effect).

Comment: Read also the [Wikipedia article on Zener diodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode).

Comment: [This other link](http://transport.ece.illinois.edu/ECE340F14-Lectures/ECE340Lecture26-ReverseBD-Dist.pdf) may give you some more hints at the physics behind the reverse breakdown in a PN junction.

Comment: You can model the zener as two imperfect (with ideality != 1, and series resistance and parallel capacitance) Shockley diodes in inverse parallel, one with a voltage source in series. That will produce the graph you show. There are more complex models.